# how to store text value for a radiogroup in sqlite database?

Tags: android, android-layout, sqlite

i've a radio group radiogoup1 that hat two radiobutton rbtn1, rbtn2. say i want to store Male for rbtn1 and Female for rbtn2 in database. How to do it? I am mentioning the .xml and .java file.

sqlliteexample.xml :

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textAge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/age" >
    </TextView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editAge"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textContcat"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/contact" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editContact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />
</LinearLayout>

 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/sLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/sx" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/RadioGroup01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/malebutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="17dp"
            android:text="@string/mal"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/femalebutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/femal"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </RadioGroup>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/savebutton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:textSize="13sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/viewbutton"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:text="@string/view"
        android:textSize="13sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

SqlLiteExample.java :

```
public class SqlLiteExample extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener {
Button sqlUpdate, sqlView;
EditText etName,etAge,etContact;
RadioGroup rdgrp;
RadioButton selectedRadioButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.sqlliteexample);
    sqlUpdate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savebutton);
    etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
    etAge = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAge);
    etContact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editContact);
    rdgrp.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    sqlView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewbutton);
    sqlView.setOnClickListener(this);
    sqlUpdate.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.savebutton:
        boolean didWork = true;
        try{
        String name = etName.getText().toString();
        String age = etAge.getText().toString();
        String contact = etContact.getText().toString();

        MyDB entry = new MyDB(SqlLiteExample.this);
        entry.open();
        entry.createEntry(name,age,contact);
        entry.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            didWork = false;
            String error = e.toString();
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("Error");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(error);
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
        }finally{
            if(didWork){
                Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Updated");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText("Success");
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();
            }

        }
        break;
    case R.id.viewbutton:
        Intent i = new Intent("com.bysakiralam.mydatabase.DISPLAYRECORDS");
        startActivity(i);
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(arg1){
    case R.id.malebutton:
        break;
    case R.id.femalebutton:
        break;
    }
} }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to override onCheckedChanged() use following in your on savebutton click

```
rdgrp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup01);
 String radiovalue=  (RadioButton)this.findViewById(rdgrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
```

and now use radiovalue to store in database

**Edit:** forget (

```
rdgrp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup01);
 String radiovalue=  ((RadioButton)this.findViewById(rdgrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
```

Comment: @SmitaS i have updated according to your code please try new updated answer !

Comment: @SmitaS i was forgetting to rename rggrp to rdgrp as per your code one alphabet is changed in above code which may be leading to create problem ! if you are getting any other problem plz let me know that ?

Comment: it says CHANGE CAST TO STRING @Tarsem

Comment: than click on that and cast to string

Comment: @SmitaS sorry for inconvenience i forget to put ( this plz check updated Answer !

Comment: db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
              KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
              KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
              KEY_AGE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
              KEY_CONTACT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
              KEY_SEX + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
              );

Comment: the first error is: 07-11 17:49:25.310: E/SQLiteLog(1026): (1) table peopleTable has no column named gender

Comment: have you updated your database File ? like if you are sending on more parameter to your createEntry(String name, String age, String contact) method it should also receive one more string parameter , as well as this value should be put in to table and table must have column for holding this new value !

Comment: this error means you don't have the column gender inside your peepelTable ! so add one column to that table before inserting the value !

Comment: Change your code to db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_AGE + "TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_CONTACT + "TEXT NOT NULL, gender TEXT NOT NULL);"

                );

Comment: before implementing my above comment check that i have edited the comment ! make sure you are coping latest code !

Comment: as you understand very well i would like to ask you another question.How to implement spinner for Age field...I want to assign 18 to 99 and as default it should show 18

Comment: i am new in this website..i know nothing..i am checking how to vote...dnt worry

Comment: if click on up arrow button than vote is given as +1 and if you click on down arrow button than vote is given as -1

Comment: check my question: How to retrieve information from SQLiteDatabase in android     and tell me how to convert EditText field to as i mentioned above

Comment: you mean you want to fill your edit text with string which you will receive from database ?

Comment: not like that..actually when entering data on the input fields such as name, age, contact etc. the age field should show 18 by default and i should able to change it through 99.

Comment: ok you can try this link  www.androidhub4you.com/2013/03/custom-picker-in-android-number-picker.html

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
myRadioGrp=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.RadioGroup01);
 String radiovalue= ((RadioButton)this.findViewById(myRadioGrp.getCheckedRadioButtonId())).getText().toString();
```